# How to keep process (stress) running till I have testcase running

Tags: linux, process, performance

I want to do stress testing of my software. I have multiple testcases with me with different runtime.

Currently, I'm running stress utility with required options and run testcase in another terminal. Once that testcase gets over, I kill stress process with ctr+C.

Now, I want to create a script which will run the stress utility and then run testcase and should be able to kill stress process after my testcase gets over.

I have a workaround as of now with stress i.e. --timeout option. So I'm running as follows:

```
stress -c 16 --timeout 3600 
./runme //Testcase script
```

After an hour, stress utility gets finished. But there is following issue with the above mentioned workaround i.e. ./runme can take 1 min to 2-3 hours of time. So I can't put timeout value beforehand.

Please suggest a way to deal with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run your `stresser` in the background and note it's `pid` which will be used to kill it later on. And now start your `testcases` in the `foreground`. After the `testsuites` finish, you go ahead n kill the `stresser` now:

```
stress -c 16 & #<--- note no timeoutoption given and assuming now it runs forever
pid_stress=$!

./rune //Testcases script

kill -9 "$pid_stress"
```

Comment: It doesn't work in practice. Actually command stress -c 16 invokes 16 processes. They are invoked by the parent stress process whose pid we get as you have mentioned. When I kill that pid, then others do not get killed and their ownership goes to its parent process.

Comment: Then in that case you need to gather the pids of those 16 childs as well. You didnt state that in your query initially. `pstree "$pid" -p -a -l > x;
kill -9 $(cut -d, -f2 x | cut -d' ' -f1)`

Comment: Of course, I didn't state that because I was assuming that you knew how stress work. Thanks a lot for your answer. It really solves my original problem. I made some minor changes in your command to avoid any file operation:
pstree $pid_stress -p -a -l | cut -d, -f2 | cut -d' ' -f1 | xargs kill -9

Comment: Meanwhile, I was trying the following in python:

os.setpgrp() # create group before stress invocation
./runme
 os.killpg(0, signal.SIGKILL) # kill all processes in my group

This has worked for me. But I will prefer your way.